# How can convert named query to sql query?

Tags: jpa

I want convert "named query" to "SQL query" in JPA 2.1 and change it before run it.

for example I have this named query: 
SELECT CU FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CU.CODE=?1 
and I want to get query after pars and convert and edit it (for example add schema name)and create this query: 
SELECT * from db1.cc1cust cu where cu.cc1cod=?1

how can I do this?

regards

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve? If so, please post it here.

Comment: for example I have this named query: SELECT CU FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CU.CODE=?1 and I want to get query after pars and convert and edit it (for example add schema name)and create this query: SELECT * from db1.cc1cust cu where cu.cc1cod=?1

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post additional information there, instead of in comments where people can't see them easily. Thanks. :-)

Comment: After re-reading your question, I realized what you're trying to do is essentially a multi-tenant setup w/ JPA.  This is not possible, the schema names are not dynamic.  The up coming Hibernate 5 will support this type of functionality, but it's not currently handled in JPA.

Answer (score 0):

The database schema can be specified on your Entity's @Table annotation or orm.xml file.

In EclipseLink, you can also set the schema using the tableQualifier in a SessionCustomizer.

There is no way to change the schema one the fly in JPQL.

To get the SQL for a JPQL query in EclipseLink you can use getSQLString() on the DatabaseQuery, see,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_get_the_SQL_for_a_Query.3F

If you are trying to implement multi-tenant support, you may wish to investigate EclipseLink's multi-tenant support,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm#BABIEJGD